# Importing Solution from Dynamic CRM Online Trial to Dynamic CRM On-Premise, activity feed issue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I sign up for Dynamic CRM online trial (30 days) and create an unmanaged custom solution (new fields, some custom entities, etc). Now, I want to export the unmanaged solution and import it to my Dynamic CRM On-Premise 2011 in my server (already get the latest rollup).

However, the solution is failed to be imported. The error message said that:

> Import of solution ***** failed. The following components are missing
>   in your system and are not included in the solution...

There are two missing components shown. Both are web resource type, with name/Id: msdyn_/ActivityFeeds.Form.Js and msdyn_/RecordWall.htm and both are ActivityFeedsCore (1.0.5.3403) managed solution.

From what I've researched, (please correct me if I'm wrong), the problem is on the Dynamic CRM online Activity Feeds managed solution are already installed and in the Dynamic CRM on-premise, it isn't.

What should I do to be able to import the unmanaged solution **without** importing the Activity Feeds managed solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `solutiondownlevelutility.exe` included in the latest CRM 2011 SDK.

You can find a guide on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945276.aspx

Comment: Just try the solutiondownlevelutility.exe, managed to past the error, however the import still fail with 1 Web Resource (html) with display name Record Wall and Name msdyn_/RecordWall.htm gives an error

Comment: At this point you can always edit manually the customizations.xml inside the soluzion zip file and remove the entry tag that refers to this Web Resource

Comment: Yes, I manually edit the customizations.xml and remove the references to the web resource and it imported well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to:
- Import the Activity Feeds.
- Import your unmanaged solution.
- Delete the Activity Feeds.

You can find the activity feeds solution here : http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-gb/applications/microsoft-dynamics-crm-activity-feeds-12884926310

Thanks,

Mario

Comment: Thanks, but I want a solution in which I don't install the activity feeds solution :)